# Jenkins "Xcode build error"

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

Developing an iOS Mobile application, While building with jenkins  , Throws
an error.

```
xcodebuild: error: The directory
/Users/nikhilchallagulla/Documents/Bombardier/workspace/014_RapidBuild_RWPS_EIC_iOS
does not contain an Xcode project or workspace."


"[014_RapidBuild_RWPS_EIC_iOS] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
xcodebuild: error: The directory
/Users/nikhilchallagulla/Documents/Bombardier/workspace/014_RapidBuild_RWPS_EIC_iOS
does not contain an Xcode project or workspace."
```

Like this please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your actual question? Would you mind to format your question appropriately?

Comment: Actually we have a iOS application code which is developer by coredova framework committed in SVN. So through jenkins we are trying to build the code from SVN source , at that time it fails with error "The directory
/Users/nikhilchallagulla/Documents/Bombardier/workspace/014_RapidBuild_RWPS_EIC_iOS
does not contain an Xcode project or workspace."  So I'm facing problem in my local directory or what ?

Comment: Is there a document in your source tree with the extension ".xcodeproj"?  That's what xcodebuild is looking for.  Alternatively is there a Makefile?  If so, try typing "make"

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build a xcode project or workspace you need to specify the location of the file or workspace in your xcode plugin(if you are using xcode plugin). You can provide the location in Advanced xcode build options. See the screenshot below. Project File ends with .xcodeproj and workspace ends with .xcworkspace extension.

[image]

Comment: Hi Nagendra,thanks for the reply. I'm confused about what to write of integrate in those parameters like Xcode Schema, SDK, SYMROOT, Xcode Workspace File, Xcode Project directory, Xcode Project file, build Output directory.  Could please give me brief about this,

Comment: Nagendra I facing new issue "/Users/nikhilchallagulla/Documents/bombardier_iOS.xcworkspace" wat is this .Xcworkspace where can i find it in my work space.